# get total count of each record from another table

Tags: django

hi I have 2 tables like this

```
class Category(models.Model):
     typeName= models.CharField(max_length=50 , null=False, blank=False ,choices=typeChoice )
     typeImage =models.ImageField( blank=True, null=True , upload_to='ActivityType')


class Products(Activity):
    activity = CharField(max_length=50 , null=False, blank=False)
    typeofproduct = models.ForeignKey(Category , on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Now in templates I want to get count of how many total Products are against each `Category`

like I did  Category.objects.all() . now for each category how many count for each product in Product table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [**`.annotate(..)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) the `Category`s:

```
from django.db.models import Count

Category.objects.annotate(
    num_products=Count('products')
)
```

The `Category` objects that arise from *this* queryset will have an extra attribute `.num_products` that contains the number of products.

You can furthermore annotate it with the existance of a `View` object, for example:

```
from django.db.models import Count, Exists, OuterRef

Category.objects.annotate(
    num_products=Count('products'),
    is_viewed=Exists(View.objects.filter(category=OuterRef('pk')))
)
```

Comment: thanks work like charm , just a small query If I want a value from other table like I have third table  "View"  there is a variable saved  isViewd  True or False. So is it possible to get that values against each record ?

Comment: So a table `View` with a `ForeignKey` to `Category`? Or `Product`?

Comment: with Category Sir

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by `Count()` method.

```
from django.db.models import Count

categories = Category.objects.annotate(total_products=Count('products'))
```

Then you can use this count by:

```
{% for cat in categories %}
   <p>Total Products: {{cat.total_products}}</p>
{% endfor %}
```